# Crawling output - connecting two variables

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I'm wondering how to combine two variables.

My goal is to that it should print out the `partnerID = 2` if I'm crawling `7236` which stands for Rome and the `partnerID = 3` if I'm crawling for e.g. `7665`which stand for Berlin.

Here is my code:

```
RegionID = {7236: 2, 7665: 3}

for reg in RegionID:
    page = 0
    while page <= max_pages:
        page += 1
        r = requests.get("http://www.spasso.com/affiliatesearch.aspx?&regionid=" + str(reg) + "&pid=" + str(page))
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

        g_data = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "gridHeadOuter productInfoOuter"})

        for item in g_data:
            Header = item.find_all("div", {"class": "offerInto"})
            Header_final = (Header[0].contents[0].text.strip())

        partner_ID = 2

        print("Header: " + Header_final + " | " + "PartnerID: " + partner_ID)
```

That is the output that I get from the code above:

```
Header: 1-hour Paris Sightseeing Cruise | PartnerID: 3

Header: Rome DC Open Top Hop-On Hop-Off | PartnerID: 3
```

Ideally the output would be like this:

```
Header: 1-hour Paris Sightseeing Cruise | PartnerID: 3

Header: Rome DC Open Top Hop-On Hop-Off | PartnerID: 2
```

I do not want use the `if...else` statement, since I will have a lot of `RegionIDs`, I'm looking for a more efficient solution.

**UPDATE**

Modified my code, since it had some mistakes. Created a dic as suggested but sill have now clue how to get it done without using every time the `if...else` statement

Comment: Try a dictionary, also please rerun your code and post that and the output.  There are problems with the code above, and it did not generate the output you showed.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Could you elaborate more on that? How do I create a dic in this case? I´m bit confused. Sorry, If I´m getting on your nerves but I´m quite new to Python

Comment: Here is a tutorial on dictionaries http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex39.html  It would connect the city name with the number you are interested in `{'Paris':2,'Rome':3}` that way you could easily get the PartnerID.  But first there are some problems with your code, so please repost working code if you need help (or non-working code with the error output)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Modified my code. Please have a look. I created a dic as your suggested but how do I get the desired result without  using every time the If else statement. Thanks for your feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your code above to get it working.  Here is an example of how you would use the `dictionary` to get `PartnerID`.

```
RegionIDArray = [7236, 7665]
dict = {7236: 2, 7665: 3} #{'Rome': 3, 'Paris': 2}
for RegionID in RegionIDArray:
    for page in range(1,2):
        url = "http://www.isango.de/affiliatesearch.aspx?&regionid=" + str(RegionID) + "&pid=" + str(page)
        html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

        g_data = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "gridHeadOuter productInfoOuter"})
        for item in g_data:
            Header = item.find_all("div", {"class": "offerInto"})
            Header_final = (Header[0].contents[0].text.strip())

        print("Header: " + Header_final + " | " + "PartnerID: " + str(dict[RegionID]))
```

The output is:

```
Header: Washington Odyssey Lunch Cruise | PartnerID: 2
Header: Audio Tour, Candlelit Dinner and Concert at Charlottenburg Palace, Berlin | PartnerID: 3
```

Comment: Glad it helped, if this question is done, please accept it to get it out of the unanswered queue.